# MySQL UPDATE table1 where table1.FIELD = table2.FIELD

Tags: mysql, set, sql-update, inner-join

I have two tables.  I want to `UPDATE` `table1` when `table1.MODEL = table2.MODEL`:
This currently updates (0) zero rows, what am I doing wrong?

```
UPDATE table1 t1
 INNER JOIN table2 t2
      ON t1.MODEL = t2.MODEL
SET t1.LINK = t2.LINK
```

This should in theory set `table1.LINK` to `table2.LINK` where `table1.MODEL = table2.MODEL` but it updates zero rows.

Comment: Probably because there is no row in `table1` that has same `model` but different `link` with a row in `table2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
UPDATE table1, table2
SET table1.link = table2.link
WHERE table1.model = table2.model
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: This is no different in results than the OP's statement.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I got `0 row(s) affected.`again

Comment: @ToddN Then are you sure that you have rows that should be affected? Try manually inserting rows with similar model but different links and execute the query. test if it runs successfully or not...

Comment: I can confirm that I have been looking at this for to long and there is indeed no MODEL that corresponds to the other MODEL in the other table, so this is why it is not updating, sorry for confusion thank you.